# Get the name and monthly salary of employee who's ID number = 1020

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following table:

[image]

And I should display the name and salary of an employee whose id = 1020. It seems like an easy question. But I don't know how to do it in Excel or Sheets.

```
SELECT name, salary FROM Employees
WHERE id = 1020;
```

That's how you display it in SQL. Could you show me the way in Excel, please?

Comment: XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or FILTER.

Comment: Examples of lookup and index with match exist on here.

Comment: =INDEX(A13:A50, MATCH(N9,B13:B50,0)). I wrote 1020 in N9. But I get an error

Comment: Probably your column references are wrong.  What's the error and what's in the various columns you reference

Comment: Note that vlookup and index/match return one column at a time.

Comment: I have updated the table picture. I don't think that column references are wrong.

Comment: They are backwards: `=INDEX(B13:B50, MATCH(N9,A13:A50,0))`

Answer (score 1):

You can go in different paths here. Imagine you have a table like so:

[image]

#### VLOOKUP Solution

One obvious solution is `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2, A1:B6, 2)
```

After that you would need to add a cell for every column you want to add, changing the third parameter on each cell.

#### QUERY Solution

But for your case maybe you are more comfortable using the `QUERY` function that reassembles a SQL.

```
=QUERY(A1:B6,"select B where A = "&E2&" label B  '' ", 1)
```

As you can see in both cases you have the same result but in the former you can modify it to get averages, max of a column, sum multiple columns and much more.

#### References

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula. =VLOOKUP(Lookup Value,Lookup Table,Column Number,Match Type)

[image]